# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field XX' doesn't have a default value, laravel y laravel-excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

sigo intentando hacer un import de datos desde un excel, pero adicionalmente necesito que en la tabla donde se insertarian los datos del excel tambien se inserten unos datos adicionales (que vienen desde la vista) pero no se como pasarle esos datos adicionales...

En mi funcion del controlador tengo una transaccion (ya que primero se debe hacer un insert a una tabla primaria):

```
public function store(Request $request){

        //$path = $request->file('serie')->getRealPath();
        //$data = Excel::import(new DetSerializacionImport, $path);
        //dd($data);
        //return $data;

        try {

            DB::beginTransaction();

            //INSERT A LA TABLA PADRE "SERIALIZACIONS"
            $serializacion = new Serializacion();

            $serializacion->fecha_serializacion = $request->get('fecha_serializacion');
            $serializacion->status = $request->get('status');
            $serializacion->usuario_id = $request->get('usuario_id');
            $serializacion->ingreso_material_id = $request->get('ingreso_material_id');
            $serializacion->det_ingreso_material_id = $request->get('det_ingreso_material_id');
            $serializacion->save();

            //INSERCION A LA TABLA MENOR "DET_SERIALIZACIONS" INCLUYENDO DATOS DEL EXCEL
            //LOS DATOS A INSERTAR VIENEN DESDE LA VENTANA MODAL

            //SE CARGA EL ARCHIVO EXCEL DESDE EL INPUT DEL MODAL
            $path = $request->file('serie')->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::import(new DetSerializacionImport, $path);

            if ($data->count() > 0) {

                foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $value) {

                    foreach($data as $row){

                        $insert_data[] = array(
                            'material_id' => $row['material_id'],//ESTE CAMPO ES ADICIONAL Y VIENE DESDE UN INPUT EN EL MODAL
                            'mac' => $row['mac'], //ESTE CAMPO VIENE DESDE EL EXCEL
                            'serie' => $row['serie'],//ESTE CAMPO VIENE DESDE EL EXCEL
                            'serializacion_id' => $row['serializacion_id'] //ESTE ID SE GENERA EN EL PRIMER INSERT Y ES LA LLAVE DE RELACION ENTRE AMBAS TABLAS

                        );

                    }

                }
                if(!empty($insert_data)){
                    DB::table('det_serializacion')->insert($insert_data);
                }
            }

            DB::commit();
            return back()->with('success', 'Insertado con exito');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //throw $th;
            DB::rollback();
        }

       //return ('hola');

    }
```

el DetSerializacionImport lo tengo asi:

```
 return new DetSerializacion([
            //
             //Columna 0 -> mac
            //Columna 1 ->Serie
            
            'mac' => $row[0],
            'serie' => $row[1]
        ]);
```

pero me da una serie de errores, por ejemplo en la linea:  if ($data->count() > 0) me dice "undefined method count", y en la linea  foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $value) me dice "Expected 2 arguments. Found 0.", ademas del tema de que no se como pasar los campos adicionales que marque en el controlador...

le quite los () en ambas lineas y ya no da error de sintaxis, pero al cargar el excel me da error:  **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'material_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `det_serializacions` (`mac`, `serie`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)**

Saludos a todos

Comment: Tus errores podrían ser que no estás recibiendo la data en el request o que no declaraste los atributos en tu modelo.

Comment: Hola @JonatanLavado, haciendo un dd al request, en el primer insert llegan bien los datos, el error se produce al tratar de hacer el segundo insert (donde vienen los datos del excel en teoria junto con los otros), en ambos modelos tengo declarados los atributos